# How to fix "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'customer' available as request attribute"?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, data-binding, annotations

I'm trying to use Spring Validation with annotations and i keep encountering the same exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'customer' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I've looked at several tutorials and double checked everything i can think of to.  I'm not sure where my problem is.  The exception happens anytime the webpage is loaded.  Any help would be appreciated.

spring-mvc-servlet.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>


    <mvc:annotation-driven/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property value="/" name="prefix"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

addCustomer.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Customer</title>

</head>
<body>
<form:form action="addCustForm"  method="POST" commandName="customer" modelAttribute="customer">
    <table border="2">
        <tr><td><form:label path="fname">Customer First Name: </form:label></td><td><form:input path="fname" id="fname"/><form:errors path="fname" cssClass="error"/> </td></tr>
        <tr><td><form:label path="lname">Customer Last Name: </form:label></td><td><form:input path="lname" id="lname"/><form:errors path="lname" cssClass="error"/> </td></tr>
        <tr><td><form:label path="phone">Customer Phone Number: </form:label></td><td><form:input path="phone" id="phone"/><form:errors path="phone" cssClass="error"/> </td></tr>
        <tr><td><form:label path="address">Customer Address: </form:label></td><td><form:input path="address" id="address"/><form:errors path="address" cssClass="error"/> </td></tr>
        <tr><td><form:label path="email">Customer E-Mail: </form:label></td><td><form:input path="email" id="email"/><form:errors path="email" cssClass="error"/> </td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Customer Info"/>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

AddCustomerController.java

```
package controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import dao.Customer;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/addCustForm")
public class AddCustomerController {



    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCustomer(@Valid Customer customer, BindingResult result, ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "addCustomer.jsp";
        }

        map.addAttribute("message",customer.getFname());
        return "Menu.jsp";
    }
}
```

Customer.java

```
package dao;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingType;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int custid;
    @Column
    @NotEmpty/*(message="First Name Is Required")*/
    /*@Pattern(regexp="{a-zA-Z}", message="First Name must be all letters")*/
    String fname;
    @NotEmpty/*(message="Last Name Is Required")*/
    /*@Pattern(regexp="{a-zA-Z}", message="Last Name must be all letters")*/
    String lname;
    @NotEmpty/*(message="Address Is Required")*/
    /*@Pattern(regexp="{a-zA-Z0-9}", message="Address must be contain only letters and numbers")*/
    String address;
    @NotEmpty/*(message="Email is Required")*/
    /*@Email(message="Invalid Email Address")*/
    String email;
    @NotEmpty/*(message="Phone Number is Required")*/
    /*@Size(min=10,max=10)
    @Pattern(regexp="{0-9}", message="Phone Number must be all Numbers(no '- or ()'")*/
    String phone;

//Getters and Setters
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <display-name>Inventory-Management-System</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Menu.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name >spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Comment: What URL handles rendering `addCustomer.jsp`?

Comment: I'm not sure.  (length)

Comment: What request do you initially send that shows you the form?

Comment: I have been using POST.

Comment: To what URL? Let's see your web.XML.

Comment: Ok i updated the question with the web.xml

Comment: Now you still need to tell us what URL you initially send a  request to before you'd expect to see the form. Which URL causes the exception you see?

Comment: http://localhost:7001/InventoryManagementProject/addCustomer.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you comments, it seems like you are sending your initial request to

```
localhost:7001/InventoryManagementProject/addCustomer.jsp
```

I'm going to assume this means that the JSP in question is at the root of the generated WAR. You can therefore access it directly without going through a Spring `@Controller`. **That, however, is the issue.**

Your JSP contains

```
 <form:form action="addCustForm"  method="POST" commandName="customer" modelAttribute="customer">
```

`<form:form>` is a tag from the Spring `form` tag library. When it is processed, it looks for request attribute named whatever is specified in the `commandName` or `modelAttribute` (note that specifying both is redundant, use only one of those). In this case, it  will look for a request attribute named `customer`, but since you haven't set such a request attribute, processing this tag will fail.

One solution, is to have your request go through a `@Controller` handler method before rendering the JSP. First, move your JSP to within `WEB-INF` and fix your `InternalResourceViewResolver` to have an appropriate `prefix` and `suffix`. Then add a handler like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-customer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAddCustomerForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
    return "addCustomer";
}
```

What this does is add a new `Customer` object in the model attributes (which end up being added as request attributes) so that it serves as a template while creating the form.

Comment: Could you explain what it was that you did "similar"?